# Azure storage static site environment variables

Tags: reactjs, azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I am serving my website front end (react) from a static site on `azure storage`

I am setting up the same website for multiple clients, each one is on its own storage account, and each one needs a unique `_id` to get its own items from the backend.

Is there a place where I can store the `_id` per account on the storage account such as an  `env variable`.

Comment: If you just want an unique id why not use your storage account name as id, your account name is already unique.

Comment: @George Chen I need the `id` match the `_id` of the client in the database, and use it from within the website to retrieve the relevant information for the client, like the  theme etc.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer, can you just add property(the _id) to the website front end in azure storage?

Comment: @Ivan Yang I could, but I want it to be dynamic per client, (each client gets their own storage instance with a copy of the front end, the only difference is the domain name and the web profile `_id` to get their specific items etc. displayed on their site)

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer not sure if I misunderstood you. Assume you have 3 clients, each client visits a static website on blob storage. And during visit, the client needs a "_id" to get their specific items, is it correct?

Comment: @Ivan Yang you are correct, by client I refer to my client, I'm creating a shopping website and using the same front end for multiple of my clients, and managing the data via saving a website profile per client and using that profile to know which items to display in each of my clients site.

Comment: You could probably use the domain used to access the website itself to differentiate between clients. Also, if you are using JWT tokens for authentication, it could be a [custom claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization#adding-application-specific-claims) (doc for AAD) that you can access in your JS code.